# keywords must come before ** argsPython(parser-16)

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and I have an application and was unable to run the server as I am getting the following error in this method " keywords must come before ** argsPython(parser-16)"  at

queryset = queryset.annotate(num_exemptions_applied=Count(Case(
            When(**annotate_filters, then=1)

the entire method as follows .Any help is appreciated.

```
    def get_queryset(self, request):
    mtr_id = self.request.query_params.get('id')
    user_terminals = request.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
    queryset = ApplicableTimeSlots.objects.filter(code__in=user)


    annotate_filters = {
        'exemptions__killed': False
    }
    if id:
        queryset = queryset.filter(mtr=id)
        annotate_filters['time_zone_id'] = mtr_id

    queryset = queryset.annotate(num_exemptions_applied=Count(Case(
        When(**annotate_filters, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )))
    return queryset.values(
        'time_zone__id', 
        'time_zone__time_slot_start'
        ).distinct().order_by("time_zone__time_slot_start")
```

Comment: Put the keyword before the `**` args, `When(then=1, **annotate_filters)`?

Comment: Where are you confused?  The error message tells you what is wrong: you have to move the keyword argument before the starred argument.